# NewRelic Not working with multiple workers Fast API Uvicorn

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, newrelic, uvicorn

We are trying to integrate NewRelic with our Fast API Service. It works fine when we are not providing numbers of worker in uvicorn config

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # newrelic.agent.register_application()
    import newrelic.agent

    newrelic.agent.initialize()
    print("api key ", os.environ.get("NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY", 1))
    print("app name ", os.environ.get("NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME", 1))
    # printing to make sure licence key and app name are defined in env variables.
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5600)
```

But when we are defining numbers of workers in the uvicorn config, NewRelic does not show any data in dashboard.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # newrelic.agent.register_application()
    import newrelic.agent

    newrelic.agent.initialize()
    print("api key ", os.environ.get("NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY", 1))
    print("app name ", os.environ.get("NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME", 1))
    # printing to make sure licence key and app name are defined in env variables.
    uvicorn.run("new_relic_test:app", host='0.0.0.0', port=5600, workers=15)
```

Is that due to multiple server process being created by uvicorn workers?

I tried removing workers and it worked fine. But with numbers of workers it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the following: when you run `uvicorn.run` with only one process, it will start the server as a normal Python function. But, when you run with `workers=n`, `uvicorn` will start `n` new processes, and the original Python process will remain as an orchestrator between these. In these new processes, it will not start your code with a different entrypoint, meaning the `if __name__ == "__main__"` will not run (this is also why you must specify your app as a string instead of the Python instance when running more than one worker, since `uvicorn` needs to know where to import your app from). So in your case, `newrelic.agent.initialize()` is not run.

I would suggest moving everything except `uvicorn.run` out of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block and put it in the same file as where you define your app.